# OpenGL / OpenCL sharing with LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, opencl, sharing, lwjgl

I can not find much about the OpenCL Java implementation in LWJGL. For instance device.isSharingSupported is not in LWJGL, or not implemented in the usual way for that matter. Can anyone elaborate on this?

So I'm interested in sharing textures / vertices from opencl with opengl.
Would it be wise to switch to JOGL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you'd query the CLDevices that support KHR_gl_sharing in LWJGL:

```
CLPlatform platform = CLPlatform.getPlatforms().get(0);
List<CLDevice> devices = platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, new Filter<CLDevice>() {
    public boolean accept(CLDevice device) {
        CLDeviceCapabilities caps = CLCapabilities.getDeviceCapabilities(device);
        return caps.CL_KHR_gl_sharing;
    }
});
```

See **org.lwjgl.test.opencl.gl.DemoFractal** in LWJGL's test package for a complete example. You can also see the source [here](http://java-game-lib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/java-game-lib/trunk/LWJGL/src/java/org/lwjgl/test/opencl/gl/).

Comment: Thanks, I looked into JOGCL / JOCL and that was pretty good as well, it had some samples etc.

Comment: Settled on LWJGL due to more suited to my needs next to OpenCL support (I don't think OpenCL support should differ that much).